# Create an XSD that supports something like web.config transforms or multi-tenant/configuration xml files

Tags: xsd, multi-tenant

I have an Xml file like this:

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/site">
    <SiteSettings>
        <ProfileGroup>TBOLoanPmtElection</ProfileGroup>
        <AWSGroup>TBOLoanPmtElection_Admin</AWSGroup>
    </SiteSettings>
</Configuration>
```

And I have an XSD file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="5.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/site" targetNamespace="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/site"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vs="http://schemas.benefittech.com/Visual-Studio-Intellisense" vs:friendlyname="Evolution Site Configuration">

    <xs:element name="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="SiteSettings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="AWSGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ProfileGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="LogActivityGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to enable my Xml to look something like the following to allow for 'environment overrides' (the E attribute on the env:* element):

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/site" xmlns:env="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/siteenvironment">
    <SiteSettings>
        <ProfileGroup>TBOLoanPmtElection</ProfileGroup>
        <AWSGroup>TBOLoanPmtElection_Admin</AWSGroup>
        <env:AWSGroup E="SecondEnvironment">TBOLoanPmtElection2_Admin</env:AWSGroup>
    </SiteSettings>
</Configuration>
```

Is there a way to modify the XSD so that given *EVERY* element in my configuration, I want to optionally have a `env:*` version of it.  Do I have to make a new schema file like below that is basically a duplicate of original except for the target namespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="5.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/siteenvironment" targetNamespace="http://schemas.benefittech.com/evolution/siteenvironment"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vs="http://schemas.benefittech.com/Visual-Studio-Intellisense" vs:friendlyname="Evolution Site Configuration">

    <xs:element name="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="SiteSettings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="AWSGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="E" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="ProfileGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="E" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="LogActivityGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="E" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is it important for you to use a separate namespace for these 'extension' elements? Because if not, I could propose a much simpler approach that (I think) would meet the requirements.

Comment: I thought I'd need separate namespaces.  I didn't want to change code everywhere that selects elements.  For example, SiteConfig.Elements( "SiteSettings" ).Elements( "AWSGroup" ).FirstOrDefault();  Would continue to work without picking up the env:* elements.  Then during the publish process, I would swap out the env:* properties everywhere and code would just work.  What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to modify the XSD so that given EVERY element in my configuration, I want to optionally have a env:* version of it.

No, there is no elegant way to add, after each element, an optional element having the same name but a different namespace. You would need to add each such env:* element individually.

> Do I have to make a new schema file like below that is basically a duplicate of original except for the target namespace?

Yes, but only if you stick to this plan of using a different namespace for the 'extension' elements. In your reply to my comment you said

> I thought I'd need separate namespaces. I didn't want to change code everywhere that selects elements. For example, SiteConfig.Elements( "SiteSettings" ).Elements( "AWSGroup" ).FirstOrDefault(); Would continue to work without picking up the env:* elements. Then during the publish process, I would swap out the env:* properties everywhere and code would just work. What's your suggestion?

I've hardly written a line of C#, but according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1 the FirstOrDefault() method returns the first element in the sequence or a default. So I think there is a much simpler approach that will not break the existing code...

On each element that needs to have option extension element(s):

1. Set maxOccurs="unbounded" (or "2", if you only want to allow one extension element)
2. Add the attribute "E" and make it optional (so that existing documents which omit it on the first occurrence are still valid).

The name "E" for the attribute is not ideal - I would pick something more descriptive if possible.

Comment: Well, I didn't fully expand my requirements.  That `FirstOrDefault` is one sample.  Other times, I get all the elements matching the requested name, so there I would need to add the filter `.Where( e => e.Attribute( "E" ) == null )` (yes, I'd pick a better name :)).  The only other thing I don't like about it is requiring that non 'E' elements would *have* to occur first in Xml for this to work.  Possible, but not ideal since I can't validate.  Will think about this suggestion though.

Comment: Personally I would go a long way before abandoning the simple approach. A different namespace for (essentially) the same type of element seems wrong, and does not even make life easy for you. Not sure why the non-'E' attributes would have to be first - surely the query language is powerful enough to pick them out wherever they are?